# -(bool) not returning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am really new to Xcode and iPhone development. I have written a function in my `appDelegate.m` file called `getISlogged;`. It goes something like this:

```
- (BOOL) getISlogged {
    NSUserDefaults *usenow = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *islog = nil;
    if(usenow){
        islog = [usenow objectForKey:@"is_log"]; // should equal 1 or 0...
    }

    UIAlertView * alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"works" message:@"test1" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert1 show];
    if (islog == [NSNumber numberWithInt:(1)]) {
       return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Ok, now i call it from my `viewController.m` like so:

```
SWGAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SWGAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSString *islog = @"no";
if(appDelegate.getISlogged){
   islog=@"yes";
}
```

Now when I run it I always get `Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1` and i have no idea what do do with that. I have tried removing all the code and leaving just `return YES;` in the function and I still get the same error =\

Any help or tips would help thank you.

Comment: You sure you haven't accidentally added a breakpoint? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just simply return the `boolValue` of the `NSNumber` instance, rather than extracting its integer value, comparing it to 1, and returning `YES` or `NO` based on that, e.g. your entire method could be reduced to:

```
- (BOOL) getISlogged {
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"is_log"] boolValue];
}
```

If the key does not exist in the user defaults, the result of this method will be `NO`.

Another “code-smell” is that you are assigning Boolean values to a string (with `@"yes"` and `@"no"` being assigned to `islog`). There is nothing wrong with that if you simply plan to write the string somewhere, e.g. to a log, but if you are planning on using this variable to determine whether or not to write to a log, then you should instead make it a `BOOL`. Strings are for storing text, that's it.

Lastly, remember that in Objective-C the `==` operator compares object identity (that is, it confirms that two references point to the same object), it doesn't compare object equality. You can use the built-in `isEqual:` methods for `NSNumber` or “extract” the boxed value and compare against another unboxed value, e.g. either of this will do the trick:

```
if ([islog isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
    // do something

// or

if ([islog intValue] == 1)
    // do something
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (islog == [NSNumber numberWithInt:(1)])
```

that's wrong. (it compares their addresses instead of their values).

Use:

```
if ([islog intValue] == 1)
```

instead.

Comment: Chances are they will point to the same object anyway. A lot of common `NSNumber` values are cached.

Comment: @dreamlax: As I'm quite sure you're aware, however, that's a classic "implementation detail which should not be relied upon".

Comment: @dreamlax the key word beingc chances

Comment: @JacquesCousteau yes I'm well aware that you shouldn't rely on it, but in this particular case I brought it up because I don't think it was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Call it as a method rather than a property:

```
if([appDelegate getISlogged]){
```

(Or declare it as a property in the app delegate.)